# Swift: UICollectionView pagination with Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, pagination, uicollectionview, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing that may have a lot of posts , a **CollectionView** for the posts and **Firebase** as the backend 
everything is good and work as expected 
but the problem is making the CollectionView using pagination (load more)
i tried doing it and it kinda work, it's just jumping in and and the screen goes to the top of CollectionView which is I'm absolutely ,
I'll show you what i did 

 Here's my **ViewDidAppear :**

```
var numOfItemsToShow = 5 //Five posts
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    ref.child("Posts").queryOrderedByChild("count").queryLimitedToLast(numOfItemsToShow).observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        var newPost = [Post]()

        for post in snapshot.children {

            let lostPost = Post(snapshot: post as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            newPost.append(lostPost)
        }

        self.posts = newPost.reverse()
        self.mainTbl.reloadData()
    })

}
```

here's what i did in **willDisplayCell** so it knows I'm at the end of posts and fire 5 more posts :

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.item == Int(numOfItems)-1 {
        numOfItems+=3
        print("update")
        ref.child("Posts").queryOrderedByChild("count").queryLimitedToLast(numOfItems).observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            var newPost = [Post]()

            for post in snapshot.children {

                let lostPost = Post(snapshot: post as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                newPost.append(lostPost)
            }

            self.posts = newPost.reverse()
            self.mainTbl.reloadData()
        })

    }
}
```

So what i'm missing here ?
 
and is it the right way to do pagination ?
if it possible show me an example that helps 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I can't answer your entire question but wanted to warn you about something that you will run in to, which is that new posts could have been added in the meantime while the user is scrolling. This would lead to double entries after you're reloading your view at the bottom. You might want to filter out any posts that are already i your array.

Comment: Thanks bro, i fix that 1 min ago and i guess i solve my own question i need to make couple tests and i'll answer

Comment: I'm curious as to how you solved the thing I mentioned. I'm also still wondering what the best solution for something like this would be. Good to hear that you managed to solve your own question!

Comment: Check the answer :) Thanks for the help Jordi

Answer (score 1):

After another look on my code 
 i found that each time i scroll to the end I'm replacing All of my existing posts with them selves and adding 3 posts 
rather then appending 3 more posts only
 
 in **willDisplayCell**

```
self.posts = newPost.reverse()
```

that cause moving my screen to the top
 
so i figured way to only appending 3 posts 
also i made couple changes
 
here's the full code 
 
**ViewDidAppear :**

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    customNav()
    mainTbl.reloadData()
    ref.child("Posts").queryOrderedByChild("count").queryLimitedToLast(numOfItems).observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        var newPost = [Post]()

        for post in snapshot.children.reverse() {// added reverse here it , it make the newest posts appear on the top of my CV

            let lostPost = Post(snapshot: post as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            newPost.append(lostPost)
        }

        self.posts = newPost //reverse removed from here
        self.mainTbl.reloadData()
    })
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}
```

**willDisplayCell :**

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.item == Int(numOfItems)-1 {
        let preNumOfItems = numOfItems //number of existed posts in CV
        numOfItems+=3 
        print("update")
        ref.child("Posts").queryOrderedByChild("count").queryLimitedToLast(numOfItems).observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            var newPost = [Post]()

            var count = 0 //counter added 
            for post in snapshot.children.reverse() {

                let lostPost = Post(snapshot: post as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                if count >= Int(preNumOfItems){ //To append only the 3 posts that are not existed
                newPost.append(lostPost)
                }
                count+=1
            }

                self.posts += newPost //append the 3 new posts to the existed posts without replacing everything
                self.mainTbl.reloadData()

        })

    }

}
```

i Hope i solve it the **good** way , at least it works :3 
Comment if you have any suggestion or question